# Allowing Anonymous authentication for non-prod environments

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

We are writing a REST Api with Jwt authentication and need to understand how to allow non-prod environments to skip the Jwt authentication functionality.

We cannot add [AllowAnonymous] on our controller because we only want it to skip the Jwt authentication in non-prod environments. This is our current attribute on the controller:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = AuthorizationDefaults.PsAuthorizePolicy)]
```

I've tried omitting the .AddJwtBearer with an if() statement as well as setting the TokenValidationParameters to null and still we cannot get by the policy.

I've thought about writing my own AuthorizationHandler like here:
[Custom authorization policies with IAuthorizationRequirementData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iard?view=aspnetcore-8.0), but unsure how to make it work with both non-prod and prod environments.

Any ideas? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: you could add another authentication method earlier in the pipeline that creates an authenticated principal that you could wrap in some conditional, simplest being a conditional compiliation

Comment: Can I add a separate policy and have it use a particular policy if on a non-prod environment? I can't really use conditional compilation as we use the same build pipelines for all environments.

Comment: Use what ever you need to identify the different environments, I could be a setting in the settings file for example

Comment: I already have the way to "compare" the environments, just not sure where to put it to allow it to skip the Jwt authentication

Comment: I had a similar problem and I added my middleware in the the owin pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I added my middleware in the the owin pipeline.

```
app.UseMyAuthMethod();
app.UseStandardAuthMethod();
```

My middleware was very simple (Omitting the actual validation method):

```
public class MyAuthMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public AgilityPassMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {

        if (AuthenticateByToken(context, out ClaimsPrincipal user))
        {
            context.Authentication.User = user;
        }

        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: We aren't using Owin, I fail to understand how to use this in our situation.

Answer (score 0):

I do have policies in a .net core app as well. When I am creating the services I  can see an opportunity for you to add a condition here if you have the appropriate policy / requirement

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 {     
     options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.IsAdministrator,
         pb => { if(isProd){ 
                 pb.RequireRole(nameof(SystemRole.DocumentAdministrator))
                } else {...}
                return pb;
          });
     options.FallbackPolicy = ..
```

Comment: I've actually tried that but it still required the Jwt.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own AuthorizationAttribute that checks whatever flag you have to control if it's a prod-environment or not.

Another option if all of your controllers require authorization is to not use the attribute on them but instead register or not register the AuthorizationAttribute filter, depending on whatever flag you have to control if it's a prod-environment or not.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#using-the-authorize-attribute

**Update:**
What about just not calling `.UseAuthentication()` and `.UseAuthorization()` when you want to allow anonymous?

Comment: Already tried not calling .Use... and it still tried to authenticate the Jwt. Now, I do like the not register the AuthorizationAttribute idea. But if you don't register it, we will still have the attribute on the controller